# Slow Java eclipse performance

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

my friend and I are using java eclipse, my labtop is 64-bit and eclipse is working fine, but on my friend's labtop - which is 32-bit - eclipse is slow when startup, slow while debugging and sometimes it stops working and responding suddenly.
Our use of eclipse most of times is to do our homeworks and courses projects.
please I appreciate any help to make eclipse performance faster.

this is the eclipse.ini configuration

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140116-2212
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi @AMH9 there are couple of more reasons than just having 64-bit or 32-bit operating system. For e.g.

1. Are there any other programs running (consuming memory, CPU when the eclipse is being used.
2. How much memory has been allocated (`Xmx`, `Xms`, `MaxPermSize`) to eclipse using eclipse.ini?
3. What programs are being executed from eclipse? does that require higher memory?

32-bit machines cannot address equal amount of memory than 64-bit can. Hence, if you can figure out the answers for above questions, it will help you determine the exact configuration to be defined in the `eclipse.ini` file.

You can get more details about setting memory parameters [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_increase_the_heap_size_available_to_Eclipse%3F).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your tips and time, but may I ask what do you mean by the first point? do you mean programs like office documents or opening other programs and files?

Comment: Hi @AMH9 You can consider office document as an example. It is more like if there are other programs which might be resource hungry (for e.g. DB or application servers or rich clients), then it will also have impact on parallel running applications (in your case it will be eclipse). This will directly result in slow down of the Eclipse application or it may terminate abruptly.

Comment: aha I see, so to check this problem we runned java without working on any other application, but still slow, so I copied the eclipse.ini code could you please check and tell which would be the best configurationof parameter for our use of eclipse and for 32-bit labtop?

Comment: @AMH9 What is the memory capacity of that computer? That is, how much RAM it has, and how much is in use when you notice Eclipse slowdowns?